# Javascript, Test if ScrollBy behaviour "smooth" is supported

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test whether or not a browser supports the scrollBy behaviour smooth.

I have the following which works for the most part but some IOS Safari versions are reporting true when they don't actually support it. I'm assuming that they do this because they support Behaviour just not Smooth Behaviour. Is there a way to test specifically for smooth behaviour? Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong in my try that's giving the false positive?

Here is my current code:

```
function testSmoothScroll() {
    let support = false;
    try {
        wrapper.scrollIntoView({
            get behavior() {
                support = true;
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // Error catching
    }
    return support;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [CSS.supports()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)?

Comment: @CBroe, CSS.supports isn't supported with IE or the new Edge. Making it a bit useless tbh for the purpose. Shame though.

Comment: With the _actual_ “new Edge”, I don’t see why it should not be supported - because that uses Chromium as rendering engine as well now. And still actively supporting IE - well that’s pain you are asking for yourself then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the `scrollBehavior` property is supported by checking the style of the HTML element.

```
const smoothScrollSupported = 'scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style;
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this. It's nice and neat but would have liked a bit more evidence behind why ScrollBehaviour is linked to Behaviour smooth on the JS methods for Scroll

Answer (score 0):

In the [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll/blob/master/src/smoothscroll.js#L10) for this feature it checks for the `scroll-behaviour` CSS property. Presumably that and JS `behavior: smooth` come together.

Comment: Didn't pick this one because it was after the one selected. But it made me take the answer. I think you're right, there must be a relationship between them.